# Jecklin Stereo with Lavs?

Tags: microphone, lavalier, stereo, ambience

Has anyone ever set up a semi-Jecklin-Disc-style stereo rig with two omni lavalieres with sound-absorbing material in between?

I suspect that a lot of us are perfectly aware of binaural recording with two lavs, often worn in or near the ears, or with a Neumann Fritz head. But I'm mulling a semi-stealth rig for stereo ambiences that captures stereo, not binaural, via a Jecklin-Disc-style baffle between the omni lavs, housed in a Rycote windjammer or even baby ball gag, if the Jecklin-esque absorber would fit. (Not unlike many [remote-capsule-mic rigs](http://thesoundmyheadmakes.blogspot.com/2011/10/recording-of-occupy-dallas.html) set up in windjammers or blimps, but those are cardioid small-condenser mics set up for ORTF, not omni lavs.)

Have you ever tried this, or seen/read accounts of something similar?

Comment: The CM3's sound great

Answer (score 1):

I'd be interested to hear the results from this if you do try.

The main question which sprang to mind is how small will your disc have to be, and how would this smaller disc affect the recording? It seems that most discs are 30 - 35cm and still require spacing between the omni's. Perhaps if you needed it smaller you could emphasise the effect by not having a flat disc, but one which is slightly parabolic on both sides or maybe even slightly ear shaped.

Comment: Great question, Mark. The diameter of the windscreen would be the limiting factor as to disc size, and I was hypothesizing that this would be OK given how small the mic capsules would be. Separation shouldn't be too hard in a normal windscreen, assuming the middle of the tube is presented to the sound source, not an end. Parabolic curvature is a neat idea I'd not considered! :)

Comment: Another thought, I use the Rycote lavalier windjammers with my DPA lavalier mics and these seem fine in moderate wind conditions. How about just using them with the Jecklin disc, or having the choice of using both (zepplin and lav windjammers) for very windy conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Well If you place it within a standard zepp and rycote it will hardly be very stealthy will it :-)
Considered doing a similar thing as well but havent found the time to actually try it yet.